# Linux: Multi IPC Wakeup or Event Signal (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, events, named-pipes, interprocess

In Linux, with C++, I need a way to have multiple client processes wait for an event and then have one main process wake up all of the other client processes once an event occurs. I do not need to pass any data between processes. I want to do this WITHOUT sockets or Boost!
The only way I know how to do this is to create a named pipe. The client processes can use a `poll()` call to block on the named pipe. Once the event needs to be fired the main process can write to the named pipe x times, where x is the number of client processes waiting on the named pipe.

It seems there should be a better way of doing this. For instance, the main process should write a '1' to the named pipe and all client processes get triggered. In the kernel we have calls like `wait_event_interruptible()` and `wake_up_all()` but what is the userspace equivalent?

Once a client process receives an event it will do some processing and then go back to waiting until another event fires.

Comment: Pthread mutexes and condition variables can be shared between processes if they are allocated in shared memory with the right settings.

Comment: Or signals. That'd be a lot simpler as long as the main process has the right permissions to send them to the clients.

Comment: @user482813
did you find a solution?